# Conditional formatting rule is never applied

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I need to make an background for cell which contains date, if the range between dates is more than 100, then it should be colored as green if not the red.
I used New formatting rule with this formula: `=IF(DAYS(F1;E1)>=100)`

so if date range is more than 100 days, then it must be green other wise red.
How can i do it?

[image]

Comment: Why do you refer to columns E:F is your data is in columns A:B???

Comment: i moved them and forgot to change column, but still it doesn't work

Comment: Try evaluate results of your coloring condition in column C. This will show you whether things are set up correctly. After success, move the condition into conditional formatting dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you don't have start and end dates in different columns (they seem to be mixed), so the function would not work.

Also when it comes to conditional formatting you should the answer should always be =True or =False, so using AND as the main function is the best option. Here is the function you needed.

=AND(IF($A1>$B1;DATEDIF($B1;$A1;"D");DATEDIF($A1;$B1;"D"))>100)

Mike

Comment: Thank You it worked, but how do i set other color if answer is false?

Comment: Just add another rule where the ending is <=100 and use the red color for that.